# Mid-80s comic that resembled French comics with a character likely named "Rodion"

Tags: story-identification, comics

I only remember fragments of this comic, of which I think I only read a single issue in the mid-80s when I was around 12-14 years old. I read it in Sweden and it was translated into Swedish.

The main character, who I am reasonably sure went by the name of Rodion was fighting monsters on some sort of artificial body which nevertheless had some sort of wilderness on it. Along with him was a woman whose name I don't remember. As I remember it, they fought together and were attacked by some sort of vaguely insectoid aircraft (plural).

The style was reasonably realistic, in color and with a sort of French comic artist's look to it (not Mœbius though).

I keep getting occasional flashbacks of this comic and want to know what it is, so I can find it and read it again!

Edit: Looks like it could be the "[La vallée des géants](https://www.comics.org/issue/1175330/#toc_1955942)" episode of "Les Robinsons de la Terre", where the name Rodion does indeed occur, along with the names Tanou, Orloz, and Zorca which are ringing all kinds of bells. I have yet to dig up any art for it, though.

Comment: Could it be [Perry Rhodan](https://www.perrypedia.proc.org/wiki/Perry_Rhodan-Comics)?  Similar name, with space adventures.

Comment: Hmm, the Perry Rhodan comics definitely remind me of the style. Thanks for the suggestion, I need to research further!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, this comic was "Les Robinsons de la Terre" drawn by Alfonso Font, written by Roger Lécureux, first published by Pif magazine, according to  http://www.albator2980.com/bd-les-robinsons-de-la-terre.htm

After I found comics.org, it was a pretty simple matter to find all comics with characters named "Rodion", and then the other character names sealed the deal.

Anything else I should add?